# How to interprete Discriminator and Generator loss in WGAN

Tags: generative-models, gan

I trained GAN with learning rate 0.00002, discriminator is trained once and generator is trained twice per epoch. Wasserstein loss is used as loss function

[image]

This is the loss graph for discriminator and generator with x-axis is epochs and y-axis is loss obtained.

Again I have trained another GAN with learning rate 0.00002, discriminator is trained once and generator is trained once per epoch.

[image]

How to interpret the loss graphs? In the first graph generator has negative loss and in second graph discriminator has negative loss. Can we have negative loss for generator?why do we get negative loss?

Comment: What loss functions are you using of the generator and the discriminator?

Comment: I have implemented WGAN

Answer (score 6):

A few points to make

- You mentioned you're using WGAN, I strongly suggest using gradient penalty instead of clipping if you aren't already.
- The generator loss is not very meaningful in WGAN. Also in general, there is nothing wrong with negative numbers at all.
- Read the WGAN paper. The theory is dense, but there are important details there.
- For example, you should train your discriminator more than your generator. Recommended values are 5-10 discriminator iters per generator iter.
- The discriminator loss is (an approximation of) the negative Wasserstein distance between the generator distribution and the data distribution. So it's actually very interpretable and useful for diagnostics.